# Camunda: How to read incident stack trace with Java API

Tags: camunda

Let's say I have incident (`org.camunda.bpm.engine.runtime.Incident`) found using `RuntimeService.createIncidentQuery()...`.

Is there a way to read actual incident stack trace using Java API? Same stack trace accessible in Cockpit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is failed job then the configuration / payload of the incident will be the job id. If the incident is caused by a failed external task then it will be the external task id.

See https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.15/org/camunda/bpm/engine/runtime/Incident.html

and
https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.15/org/camunda/bpm/engine/ManagementService.html#getJobExceptionStacktrace-java.lang.String-

and
https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.15/org/camunda/bpm/client/task/ExternalTask.html#getErrorDetails--

Hence:

```
Incident incident = runtimeService.createIncidentQuery().singleResult();
String configuration = incident.getConfiguration();

log.info("Incident type: {}", incident.getIncidentType());
if (incident.getIncidentType().equals(Incident.FAILED_JOB_HANDLER_TYPE)) {
    log.info("Here comes the stacktrace: {}", managementService.getJobExceptionStacktrace(configuration));
} else {
    log.info("Here come the error details: {}", externalTaskService.getExternalTaskErrorDetails(configuration));
}
```